# Unable to assign a click event to an eventhandler that uses an extended eventargs argument

Tags: c#, winforms, events, toolstripmenu

I am trying to assign an event handler that uses an event argument that extends System.EventArgs to a ToolStripMenuItem. When I enter the name of the handler it wants to create an event handler that uses System.EventArgs.  This is for a list of recent files.

Here is the code

```
RecentEventArgs e = new RecentEventArgs();
e.FileName = item;
ToolStripMenuItem recentItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item);
recentItem.Click += new EventHandler(RecentItem_Click);
mnuFileOpenRecentList.DropDownItems.Add(item);

private void RecentItem_Click(object sender, RecentEventArgs e)
{
    MessageManager.DisplayMessageBox("File -> Open Recent ->");
    OpenRecentFile(e.FileName);
    }

public class RecentEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string fileName;

    public RecentEventArgs()
        :base()
    {

    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return fileName; }
        set { fileName = value; }
    }
}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The event is fired by the ToolStripMenuItem, and that one does not "know" about the FileName property, so how should it be able to fire an event with RecentEventArgs?

Comment: I am inheriting from the EventArgs class and extending it with the FileName property, and using it in the event handler

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction but you missed some key parts. Keep in mind that everything in c# is strongly typed which means that all method signatures can't change their any of their arguments at runtime. This also true for [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) (that is what you're using if you are subscribing to events).

As you already have your custom EventArgs, what is still missing is a delegate that describes the method signature your new event (because that is what you're after) will be calling.

```
// the public delegate with the custom eventargs
public delegate void RecentEventHandler(object sender, RecentEventArgs e);
```

Now you want something that acts as a ToolStripMenuItem but fires the Recent event is it gets clicked and send your custom eventargs as the payload. Let's create a subclass to handle that logic:

```
public class RecentFileMenuItem:ToolStripMenuItem
{
    private string filename; // holds your path+file

    // constructur
    public RecentFileMenuItem(string filename)
        :base(Path.GetFileName(filename))
    {
        // keep our filename
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    // event delegate, subscribe to this
    public RecentEventHandler Recent;

    // click invokes all subscribers 
    // for the Recent Event
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        RecentEventHandler recent = Recent;
        if (recent !=null)
        {
            // create your RecentEventArgs here
            recent(this, new RecentEventArgs { FileName = filename });
        }
    }
}
```

In the above class I override the default OnClick handler to invoke any subscribers to the Recent event where we create a new RecentEventArgs. Notice the `Recent` delegate of type `RecentEventHandler`.

With this bits working we need to bring our class into play.

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecentFileMenuItem recentItem = new RecentFileMenuItem("foo");

        mnuFileOpenRecentList.DropDownItems.Add(recentItem);

        recentItem.Recent += new RecentEventHandler(Show); 
    }

    // method signature that matches our RecentEventHandler delegate
    public void Show(object s, RecentEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.FileName);
    }
```

Here we see that we add a new instance of the `RecentFileMenuItem` with a filename in the constructor to the recent list. The `Show` method matches the signature and so we can subscribe to the `Recent` event with the delegate pointing to that method.